# openCV distortion calibration resolution scaling

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a camera matrix and undistortion coefficients that I found [here](http://www.htw-mechlab.de/index.php/undistortion-der-gopro-hd-hero2/) for some GoPro footage (because I unfortunatly no longer have access to a GoPro to calibrate the footage myself), and it seems to work well enough for 1280 * 960 (4:3), however, I am running into some issues with larger resolutions (3840 * 2880 (4:3)).

[According to the openCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html):

> While the distortion coefficients are the same regardless of the camera resolutions used, these should be scaled along with the current resolution from the calibrated resolution.

Is `these` referring to the camera matrix? What is the exact procedure to scale the camera matrix? I tried linear interpolation (scalar multiplication of row X with width ratio and row Y with height ratio), the image is better but still doesn't look quite right. Could this be because the video aspect ratio of the calibration footage (16:9) isn't quite the same as my footage? If so, why would the error not scale linearly as well?

E.g.

```
f_x_target = f_x_calibration * targetWidth / calibrationWidth
c_x_target = c_x_calibration * targetWidth / calibrationWidth
f_y_target = f_y_calibration * targetHeight / calibrationHeight
c_y_target = c_y_calibration * targetHeight / calibrationHeight
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GoPro camera has different field of view at different resolutions. Take a look at the [specs](http://gopro.com/cameras/hd-hero3-black-edition#technical-specs).  This is probably what's causing your problems.